# How To handle click events of different charts on the same page

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, vue.js, chart.js

I want to call a method to handle click event from this vue file:

```
<template>
    <Chart
        type="bar"
        :labels="labels"
        :datasets="datasets"
        :options="options"
    ></Chart>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue, Watch } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import Chart from '@/components/Chart.vue';
import { colors } from '@/constants';

@Component({
    components: {
        Chart
    },
})
export default class AlarmsChart extends Vue {
    @Prop()
    public stats!: any[];

    ...

    get options() {
        const options = {
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            scales: {
                yAxes: [
                    {
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Number of alarms',
                        },
                    },
                ],
                xAxes: [
                    {
                        type: 'time',
                        time: {
                            parser: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
                            displayFormats: {
                                day: 'DD/MM/YY',
                            },
                        },
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Date',
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
            legend: {
                labels: {
                    fontFamily: 'Overpass',
                },
            },
            'onClick' : (event, item) => {
                if ( item.length == 0 ) return; // Clicked outside any bar.
                clickHandler(event);
            },
        };
        return options;
    }
}
</script>
```

To this one:

```
<template>
    <div class="chart-container">
        <canvas ref="chart"></canvas>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue, Watch } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import Chart from 'chart.js';

/**
 * The Chart component acts as a wrapper around Chart.js.
 *
 * This component has various properties that will be passed onto Chart.js.
 * This component should be as generic as possible to allow different kinds of
 * charts with different kinds of datasets in order to encourage reuse of this
 * component without having to deal with tedious workarounds.
 */
@Component
export default class ChartComponent extends Vue {
    @Prop()
    public datasets!: any;

    @Prop()
    public labels!: string[];

    @Prop()
    public options!: any;

    @Prop()
    public type!: string;

    private chart?: Chart;

    public mounted() {
        // Since we are updating the UI ourselves, always create the chart
        // *after* Vue has finished rendering the DOM.
        const chartElement = this.$refs.chart as HTMLElement;
        this.chart = new Chart(chartElement, {
            type: this.type,
            data: {
                labels: this.labels,
                datasets: this.datasets,
            },
            options: this.options,
        });
    }

    public clickHandler(evt) {
        var firstPoint = this.chart.getElementAtEvent(evt)[0];

        if (firstPoint) {
            var label = this.chart.data.labels[firstPoint._index];
            var value = this.chart.data.datasets[firstPoint._datasetIndex].data[firstPoint._index];
        }
    }

    /** Automatically update Chart.js upon dataset changes. */
    @Watch('datasets', { deep: true })
    private onChange() {
        this.chart.data.labels = this.labels;
        this.chart.data.datasets = this.datasets;
        this.chart.update();
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.chart-container {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

In the first file in options there is a method call inside the onClick event to: clickHandler(event), I want to call to the method that is in the second file. But no idea how to do it, is it possible?

I want to do this to get data from the bar clicked. So the second file is like a common chart, and the first one is a custom. Several files like the first one use the second file.

Comment: how u insert mutiple chart ??

Comment: the second file is included into the first one in the template

Comment: i mean u have created only one variable this.chart to assign. How you will work with that ?? u need array of charts and assign id to all. Once event trigger, u check id and perform. else create a wrapper component, move all common method in that. to separate out concern.